# What if my door handle height too low?

Tags: doors, inspection

One of the door handles in my basement is less than 34" above the floor. It is actually 33". This door is the entrance to a bathroom and is positioned beneath a bulkhead.

Will this be an issue with the inspection? Or do I need to try to adjust the door? (pre-hung door with little to no clearance above it).

Comment: What inspection? By whom? Where? Please revise to provide enough information for us to answer.

Comment: Was it placed there for a reason, for a disabled person, or did someone goof up?

Comment: How are you measuring height?

Comment: Measured from floor to center of the door handle hole.

Comment: Just measured some of my door handles.  Have one at 33 also and find it quite comfortable to reach with my hand, almost perfect.  Others are higher and need to raise my hand a bit to handle them.  Do not know the code height for doors.

Comment: If you don’t want to damage or change the door, then you could lower the floor.

Comment: @SolarMike how does one lower a basement floor for a doorway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No one can tell what a particular inspector will do with a specific noncompliance issue on a particular day.

You may be asked to remediate it, or the issue may be ignored.

Comment: i'm hoping for the latter. It's 1"... I could raise it up, but would have to alter the casing and it would look bad.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing in the Code that mandates the height of door hardware (door handles) in private single family residences.

However, if the residence is designated an “accessible dwelling “ or if it’s designated “historic structure” then it will need to comply with those requirements. There is a height requirement for door hardware (48” maximum, see 1109.9.8)

If a fussy inspector wants to reject the mounting height, I’d invoke “Alternate Method” clause (See 1101.3) which allows you to use an alternate method if it gives you essentially the same result. (It’s a little known clause and inspectors hate it.)

Comment: I did a fast google on this and every tidbit listed minimum 34 inch from the floor.max 48 inches.  They mention it was in the building code.  I have not read the code and wondering if you can explain better.  Maybe it is for commercial?

Comment: I use the International Code Council (ICC) which is what most jurisdictions in the U.S. use. I followed your lead and googled a search for door hardware and found a Code for New York City that did specify the 34-48” range. The code seems to be for commercial work, which would make sense for that location.